# jQuery / Javasript : Run code after changing url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, url

I want to run code after changing a page with an `<a></a>`. The code execute on the current page and after running all the code, it change page. I want that after clicking the `<a></a>` element, some code is runned on the new page.

this is my html :

```
<a href="index.html" class="hello">
    <p>En savoir plus</p>
</a>
```

And this is my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".hello").click(function () {
        //Code that I want to run
        console.log("hey");
    });
});
```

Hope there is a solution.

Comment: Show how you change url

Comment: The problem is if you click on `<a class="hello"...>` the URL follows the href. For a browser that means load the "new" URL. Which will also reload the javascript. You should update your question and explain more what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I change the url with the '<a></a>' element in the html.

Comment: @caramba I changed my question even tho someone answer, I hope it is more clear and that I can help other people that have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the code as below to prevent default action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Grab the event object (e)
  $(".hello").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Add this
    //Do something after the a element loaded the new page
    console.log("hey");
  });
});
```

Also, if you have more clarifications do update your question (if the above solution doesn't work after you try it out)

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Have a good day!

Comment: Great.  Please mark the answer as accepted in that case.  Thanks. – @gabgab06